# js files loading twice in Ie8

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer-8

I am loading my .js files in the following way, and I am getting some of these js files loaded twice in IE8 in my production site. However there is no issue in Development/QA/Management sites. Any ideas on what might be the issue?

```
head.js('<%=cloudFrontURL + "/" + ics.GetVar("constant:siteTheme") + "/" + uiDirectoryName + "/deploy/dev/js/libs.js"%>',
        '<%=cloudFrontURL + "/" + ics.GetVar("constant:siteTheme") + "/" + uiDirectoryName + "/deploy/dev/js/plugins.js"%>',
        '<%=cloudFrontURL + "/" + ics.GetVar("constant:siteTheme") + "/" + uiDirectoryName + "/deploy/dev/js/utils.js"%>',  
        '<%=cloudFrontURL + "/" + ics.GetVar("constant:siteTheme") + "/" + uiDirectoryName + "/deploy/dev/js/modules.js"%>', 
        '<%=cloudFrontURL + "/" + ics.GetVar("constant:siteTheme") + "/" + uiDirectoryName + "/deploy/dev/js/app.js"%>', function() {
            //jwplayer.key="4r9NQzYgXQ74/1mE9/lVdi9m4Ckq1ukFXyBxDA==";
            $(function() {
                Loader.init();
                    });
        });
```

Thanks in advance..!!

Comment: One more observation is that all the .js except the first one are getting loaded twice

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that this is a known bug with head.js for IE versions and can be avoided by using this format -

```
head.js("script file 1").js("script file 2").js("script file 3");
```